# Merge (nest) two json object VB

Tags: json, vb.net

I have two json objects that originate from two seperated databases I need to merge them.

Json1: from Product database

```
1[{"prod": "Product1", "price": 12.99, "stock": 243, "description": "prod1 description"}]
```

Json2: from Review database

```
    1[{"reviewer": "reviwerX", "review": "this is review from X"},
{"reviewer": "reviwerY", "review": "this is review from Y"}, 
{"reviewer": "reviwerZ", "review": "this is review from Z"}]
```

I need to merge these using VB so that I get:

```
    product[{"prod": "Product1", 
             "price": 12.99, 
             "stock": 243, 
             "description": "prod1 description", 
             "reviews" :[
                    {"reviewer": "reviwerX", "review": "this is review from X"},
                    {"reviewer": "reviwerY", "review": "this is review from Y"}, 
                    {"reviewer": "reviwerZ", "review": "this is review from Z"}]}]
```

I have not been able to find example to do this. I've found plenty of examples to merge (joining) json objects with the same data fields but not nesting objects the way I need.

Comment: Json is the serialized text for an object, it is not an object itself. You'll need to add a `List(of review)` to the product class

Comment: I have solved this... I went back a step. Created a single model that queried the two databases and then using Newtonsoft.json I 'wrote' out the json as I needed. Basically replacing the two gets with a single get and no need to manipulate further.

Comment: @Mych You should consider adding your solution (including code) as an answer to your own question.  This would help other people who have the same issue.